# perl remove identical id and similar id, maintain the array order and print them like matrix

Tags: perl, printing, duplicates

my first file have some keys. Example,

```
Eur1
Eur2
Eur3
Eur4
Eur5
```

the other file is the actual input. separated by ":" (headers are on the left side. right side is "|" delimited matching ids) it will look like,

```
Eur2_1116: Eur1_9816|Eur1_916|Eur3_16|Eur4_17|Eur5_716
Eur3_2980: Eur1_8568|Eur2_98|Eur2_92|Eur4_12.3|Eur4_12.1|Eur4_12.9
Eur4_786: Eur2_0909|Eur5_1090|Eur5_2535|Eur1_233
Eur1_10616: 
Eur5_5634: Eur3_1868|Eur4_8634|Eur1_35923
Eur1_34312: 
Eur3_0000: Eur5_8235
Eur3_3433: 
Eur5_3354: Eur2_245|Eur2_245|Eur1_34
Eur3_1122: Eur4_4431
```

in my definition,

identical ids are identical. example (Eur2_245, Eur2_245 at line 9)

similar ids are derived from the same key with different value. example (Eur1_9816 and Eur1_916 at line1) or (Eur4_12.3,Eur4_12.1 and Eur4_12.9 at line 2).

I want to remove the identical ids. Also, the similar ids after first match. Example, Eur1_9816 should go the output line 2. or Eur4_12.3 for line 2. Because, they are the first similar id among other similar ids.

my desired output should be like matrix, having the headers in the first column exactly like the input headers. Followed by the ordered keys in the consecutive columns. Of note, headers are also belongs to one of the ordered keys. So header itself become a matching id at a respective column.

Example, line 1, Eur2_1116 is the header.
It will be in the line 1 as header and ALSO it will be part of "Eur2" ordered key column.

And similarly all other respective matches (after excluding identical, similar matches) should go to the respective columns.

Desired output #1

```
Column1 Eur1    Eur2    Eur3    Eur4    Eur5

Eur2_1116       Eur1_9816       Eur2_1116       Eur3_16 Eur4_17 Eur5_716
Eur3_2980       Eur1_8568       Eur2_98 Eur3_2980       Eur4_12.3
Eur4_786        Eur1_233        Eur2_0909               Eur4_786        Eur5_1090
Eur1_10616      Eur1_10616
Eur5_5634       Eur1_35923              Eur3_1868       Eur4_8634       Eur5_5634
Eur1_34312      Eur1_34312
Eur3_0000                       Eur3_0000               Eur5_8235
Eur3_3433       Eur3_3433
Eur5_3354       Eur1_34 Eur2_245                        Eur5_3354
Eur3_1122                       Eur3_1122       Eur4_4431
```

my actual code is, (after =for commented lines, these code block is wrong). could you please correct it. If possible, to track back the identical and similar matches, can i write it in a separate file?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $ipArr = $ARGV[0]; chomp $ipArr; #setArr.txt
open (IN,"$ipArr") or die "Unalbe to open the file:$!\n";

my $orderArr = $ARGV[1]; chomp $orderArr; #orderArr.txt
open(OA,"$orderArr") or die "Unable to open the order array:$!\n";
my @orderKeys = <OA>; chomp @orderKeys; close OA;

while (my $line = <IN>) 
{
    chomp ($line);
    my ($header,$matchSet) = "";
    my (@tmpSet, @setArr1, @setArr2) = ();
    ($header,$matchSet) = split("\:",$line);
    $matchSet =~ s/\s+//g;
    @tmpSet = split (/\|/, $matchSet);
    push(@setArr1,$header,@tmpSet);
    sub uniq {
        my % seen;
        grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
    }
    @setArr2 = uniq(@setArr1);
    print join "\t", @setArr2,"\n";
}

=for
    foreach my $g (@setArr2)
    {
        my ($k,$val) = "";
        $g =~ /^(\w.*)\_(\w.*)$/;
        $k = $1; $val = $2;
        $hash{$k} = {$val};
    }
}   
    foreach $S (@orderKeys)
        {
            if($setArr[$i] =~ /^$S\_.*$/)
            {
            print "$S\t";
            }
        }
    }

    print "\n";
}   
close IN;
```

Comment: Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your script and run it again. What does it tell you?

Comment: Yes, I do and  I get a output in which only the identical ids are removed and no order like in the orderArr.txt. Because after "=for" commented, the loop iterates nothing but wrong.

Comment: push(@setArr1,$header,@tmpSet); Please check this push options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open FH,"tmp1" or die "Error\n";#orderArr.txt
my %myhash;
my $count++;
my @firstarray = ("Eur1","Eur2", "Eur3", "Eur4", "Eur5");
while (<FH>){
        chomp($_);
        my @val = split(/:/,$_);
        $val[1] =~ s/\s//;
        if($val[1] ne "")
        {
                my @arr = split(/\|/,$val[1]);
                foreach my $id (@arr)
                {
                        my @val1 = split(/_/,$id);
                        push(@{$myhash{$count}{$val[0]}{$val1[0]}},$id);
                }
        }
        my @val1 = split(/_/,$val[0]);
        push(@{$myhash{$count}{$val[0]}{$val1[0]}},$val[0]);

        $count++;
        #print "$val[0]\n";

}
foreach my $count (sort { $a <=>  $b} keys %myhash)
{
        foreach my $id (keys %{$myhash{$count}})
        {
                print "$id";
                foreach my $idlist (@firstarray)
                #foreach my $idlist(keys %{$myhash{$count}{$id}})
                {
                        #print " t $idlist t ";
                        if(exists $myhash{$count}{$id}{$idlist})
                        {
                                my $value =$myhash{$count}{$id}{$idlist}[0];
                                print "\t$value";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                print "\t";
                        }
                }
                print "\n";

        }
}
```

Output :

```
Eur2_1116       Eur1_9816       Eur2_1116       Eur3_16 Eur4_17 Eur5_716
Eur3_2980       Eur1_8568       Eur2_98 Eur3_2980       Eur4_12.3
Eur4_786        Eur1_233        Eur2_0909               Eur4_786        Eur5_1090
Eur1_10616      Eur1_10616
Eur5_5634       Eur1_35923              Eur3_1868       Eur4_8634       Eur5_5634
Eur1_34312      Eur1_34312
Eur3_0000                       Eur3_0000               Eur5_8235
Eur3_3433                       Eur3_3433
Eur5_3354       Eur1_34 Eur2_245                        Eur5_3354
Eur3_1122                       Eur3_1122       Eur4_4431
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you wanted to call out removing duplicates if your end goal is to find the first item from each category that exists on the line, but I've kept that call in in case you're doing something not shown here using it. The code you have in your first for loop works except you want to assign `$val` instead of `{$val}` and from your problem description,you want the first match which means you want to use `//` (or if in ancient perl `||`) giving you `$hash{$k} //= $val;`

Then your second loop would become

```
foreach $S (@orderKeys)
{
  if(defined $hash{$S})
  {
      print "$S\t";
  }
}
```

(That doesn't print out what you want, but it's the minimal change to make that code "work")

If you want some cleaned up code that does everything you described in your sample please take a look at the below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# List::Util also exports uniq, but the stock one usually doesn't so
# you may still need to define it if you don't want to upgrade to the
# newest version of the library for some reason.
use List::Util qw(first uniq);

my ($ipFilename, $orderFilename) = @ARGV;

# The 3 argument open is preferred for safety and using a scalar
# instead of a global bareword will help your sanity if you ever
# want do put these things in subroutines.
open(my $ip, '<', $ipFilename) or die "Unable to open $ipFilename for read: $!";
my @orderKeys = do {
  open(my $order, '<', $orderFilename) or die "Unable to open $orderFilename for read: $!";
  <$order>;
};
chomp(@orderKeys);

# Tell perl to print array elements joined with tabs.
local $" = "\t"; # comment to fix github formatting "

print "Column1\t@orderKeys\n";

while (my $line = <$ip>) {
  chomp($line);
  my ($header, $matches) = split(/\s*\:\s*/, $line, 2);
  my @matches = ($header, split(/\s*\|\s*/, $matches));
  # I don't use or need this, but if you need it for some other purpose, it can still be here
  my @uniqueMatches = uniq @matches;
  # Get the first item from each category that starts with the given key.
  my @slots = map { my $key = $_; first { /^\Q$key\E/ } @matches } @orderKeys;
  no warnings 'uninitialized';
  print "$header\t@slots\n";
}
```

Comment: This is what I got when I ran this script. "uniq" is not exported by the List::Util module. Since you mentioned already regarding this, I defined only, use List::Util qw(first) and commented the line "my @uniqueMatches = uniq @matches;". It gives the desired output. Thank you for the corrections and the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my take is want you want. If the column 1 id matches any of the subsequent ids on a line, any subsequent matching id will not be listed. Instead, the col 1 id will be used (in it's respective position).

**Update:** Added the '++' after the seen hash - I omitted it originally.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @order_keys = qw/
Eur1
Eur2
Eur3
Eur4
Eur5
/;

my $fmt = "%-15s" x 6 . "\n";
printf $fmt, '', @order_keys;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($id, @data) = split /[:\|\s]+/;
    my %seen;
    my %tmp = map {@$_}
              grep !$seen{$_->[0]}++,
              map {[ /^([^_]+)/, $_ ]} ($id, @data);

    printf $fmt, $id, map $_ // '', @tmp{@order_keys};
}

__DATA__
Eur2_1116: Eur1_9816|Eur1_916|Eur3_16|Eur4_17|Eur5_716
Eur3_2980: Eur1_8568|Eur2_98|Eur2_92|Eur4_12.3|Eur4_12.1|Eur4_12.9
Eur4_786: Eur2_0909|Eur5_1090|Eur5_2535|Eur1_233
Eur1_10616: 
Eur5_5634: Eur3_1868|Eur4_8634|Eur1_35923
Eur1_34312: 
Eur3_0000: Eur5_8235
Eur3_3433: 
Eur5_3354: Eur2_245|Eur2_245|Eur1_34
Eur3_1122: Eur4_4431
```

Output:

```
               Eur1           Eur2           Eur3           Eur4           Eur5
Eur2_1116      Eur1_9816      Eur2_1116      Eur3_16        Eur4_17        Eur5_716
Eur3_2980      Eur1_8568      Eur2_98        Eur3_2980      Eur4_12.3
Eur4_786       Eur1_233       Eur2_0909                     Eur4_786       Eur5_1090
Eur1_10616     Eur1_10616
Eur5_5634      Eur1_35923                    Eur3_1868      Eur4_8634      Eur5_5634
Eur1_34312     Eur1_34312
Eur3_0000                                    Eur3_0000                     Eur5_8235
Eur3_3433                                    Eur3_3433
Eur5_3354      Eur1_34        Eur2_245                                     Eur5_3354
Eur3_1122                                    Eur3_1122      Eur4_4431
```